# Date range in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m looking to find "books" between specific dates.

I have a variable publishdate and want to get all the books which have a publish date between to dates, but I´m not sure which operator to use.

I tought of something like this but it´s not working

```
@books = Book.where(:e_release_date => 20141217 && :e_release_date <= 20141017)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using ActiveRecord. In ActiveRecord you can query between like this:

```
@books = Book.where(:e_release_date => 20141217..20141017)
```

Comment: It is weird, if I use @books = Book.where(:e_release_date => 20141217) then it works but yours won´t work. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Ok i worked , the dates just where in the wrong order :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for `date1` and `date2`

```
data = Book.where(e_release_date: Date.parse(params[:date1])..Date.parse(params[:date2]))
```

It will give you data for date `2014-10-17` and `2014-12-17`

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE (books.e_release_date BETWEEN '2014-10-17 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-17 00:00:00')
```